# Parcelable out of memory

Tags: android, parcelable

Suppose we have a list of complex objects (primitives and other objects inside) requested from a server to show them inside a `RecycleView`. In adapter we need only some data from each object, let's say 70%.

I get from server list with full data objects, and each object implements `Parcelable` so when I select a item I pass object via intent to `MyDetailsActivity` like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyDetailsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("foo", myComplexObject);
startActivity(intent);
```

This is working as expected but on some low memory devices I get out of memory errors. So my question is **how to achieve this type of data flow**?

One possible solution is to implement get/set for `MyObj` in `Applicattion` class, and pass it like so but I'n not sure if it's stable.

And of course I can pass just an id from `MyObject` and do another request call inside `DetailsActivity`'s `onCreate()`, but this requires user to wait some more seconds to load data.

Any advices or references are apreciated

Comment: show your logcat results.

Comment: @NoumanCh I just posted the core of my problem, error logs are irrelevant

Comment: The best approach is to store those objects in database. In addition to solving memory issues, this will automatically make the application less network-dependent and lay foundation for editing data on client side (if you are going to ever need that). When you know, that some consistent snapshot of data is readily available from DB, coding becomes *a lot* simpler, — you won't need to scatter all that error-handling code around your activities anymore!

Answer (score 3):

As you have experienced, sending data through the bundle/intent extras has its memory limits.

Your options are to either keep those objects in memory and access them via some static/singleton instance or to do the data query from your server in the desired activity that will show them in your list.

Another viable options is to store the data in a database for ex and read it once its required but this ofcourse depends on your current architecture... you can checkout Realm, Room, GreenDao database options etc...

Answer (score 0):

Second approach is more suitable for mobile applications since you only load data in list via API which is visible inside the recycler view, you can pass that data to activity and then in activity load the remaining data from another call for that specific item.

I'm assuming that each object of the data coming from the server is not of same size, leading to out of memory on some but not all the objects. So the better approach is to also modify server apt (if possible) to send only info which is required for the list in your call's response and have separate resource url to access full information for that object.

This may result in a minimal delay but it will not cause unexpected out of memory errors which is a big let down for the end user.

Comment: also the @JabBo answer is very good approach to store the data coming from API in database and then each activity can access it when required.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use `Application` class for this purpose, to make it even better

1. Set the `data` in `Application` class when you intend to pass
2. Retrieve the `data` at destination into Local variable from `Application`
3. After retrieving `data` into local variable, set `object` in `Application` to `null`

Using above approach will make sure your objects memory is released as soon you consumed it without holding it all the time throughout Application Lifecycle

Comment: Actually this can be considered an anti pattern since application object is destroyed if app is not visible and device runs low memory, so when user returns to my app, Android recreates Application object without my stored data.